# https to http change url through .htaccess in magento sites except checkout or my account page

Tags: url-rewrite, ssl, https

All my pages are indexed with https: URL in Google because in the past my my secure base URL and unsecure base URL both were https://www.example.com

Now my secure base URL is https://www.example.com
an unsecure base URL is http://www.example.com

Such that checkout and customer pages open with https://www.example.com
and all other pages open with http://www.example.com

#### Issue:

As my all page are indexed as https in Google, I want to redirect https non checkout and non customer URLs to http

I tried with this `.htaccess` code, without success:

```
RewriteEngine on
# From https to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/account/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/multishipping/login/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wishlist/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# From http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/cart/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/account/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/multishipping/login/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wishlist/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: my requrement is i try to hits one url https://www.example.com/ its change to http://www.example.com

Answer (score 2):

This code solved this problem

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(shop|blog|stockists|inthepress|contacts|review|home) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R]
```

Comment: Can you please add your full example. I mean to say with the URI on which you want http and on which you do not want. Thank you very much.